# Pthread and keyboard

Tags: c++, keyboard, pthreads

I want to know how to run a thread to sleep some time every time I press a key. For example, if I press the same key twice, it should have two threads to sleep for a while.

I *MUST* use **pthreads** and **C++**.

Honestly I have tried many ways but I still do not know how to solve it.

Sorry if my english is not very good :)

**UPDATE**

This is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
int a;
void* executer2(void*)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (a > 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    cout << "Thread: " << pthread_self() << endl;
    sleep(a);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* executer(void*)
{
    int key;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        key = cin.get();

        if (key == 'a') {
            cout << "Sleep for 4 seconds" << endl;
            a = 4;
        } else if (key == 'b') {

            cout << "Sleep for 8 seconds" << endl;
            a = 8;
        } else {

            cout << "Sleep for 2 seconds" << endl;
            a = 2;
        }

        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tr, t;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&tr, &attr, executer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t, &attr, executer2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tr, NULL);
    pthread_join(t, NULL);

}
```

Comment: What specific part are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far? Are the threads successfully spawning?

Comment: I can create a thread, but if I press a key again, I must wait until my other thread finish for my new thread executes

Comment: From what you said, you are joining threads together when pressing next key, just don't join them and simply create a new one, like you did with the first one.

Comment: please show us the code which is causing you problems.

Comment: @didierc Ready! Here is my code...

Comment: @Chu it's sad that you _have_ to use pthreads. `std::thread` is so much more eye-friendly

Comment: @stefan yes, but it is the tool that I'm programming now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. since you want to create a thread each time you press a key, and that the keypress handler is in `executer`, you should move the code to create `executer2` in `executer`.
2. `executer` is made to `sleep` 1 sec. after reading a key press, but it seems that's not what you want. Just remove that call to `sleep(1)` to get an immediate response
3. the code of `executer` seems to indicate that you wish to modulate the time spent sleeping by the thread depending on the input key. You can pass the sleep time as a parameter to `executer2`, as indicated by the `void *` parameter of that function. The idea is to cast the time value to a `void *`, pass it at thread creation time, and cast it back to int within `executer2`:

   ```
   // executer2 thread creation 
   pthread_create(&t, &attr, executer2,(void *)a);
   ```

   and in `executer2`:

   ```
   void *executer2(void *arg){
       int a = (int)arg;
       // ...
   ```

   The thread creation code should go after the switch in `executer2`, and you should not need the global `a` variable anymore.
4. you are currently using a mutex to lock the code of `executer2`. This will prevent all the sleeping threads to sleep together at the same time. You will have to remove the lock to allow them to sleep concurrently (but leave the lock around the text output).
5. you say that you wish a C++ solution. You could benefit from using the thread library from the stl, which wraps the OS thread primitives (pthreads in your case) with higher level constructs and are easier to manipulate, especially for parameters. It would be a good exercise to convert your programme to use this library once you have the current code working.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do I need my conditionals?

Comment: what for? There's no synchronization logic needed between executor 1 and 2, and the sole sync. problem between executor2 instances is addressed by the mutex.